# Copy paste multiple value to Choices field in SPO edit grid

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, quick-edit

We have an Excel file with 300 rows of data and would like to copy & paste into a SPO list.
However one of the field is "Choices" field with multiple selection. When paste into SharePoint edit grid it keep prompt me for format error.

How can I reformat my excel in order to copy & paste into Choices field with multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you should format date ;A;B;C;D; in the excel file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and when I used PowerShell to upload from the CSV.

I needed `;#` between choice values.  `A ;` didn't work for me.